# How to launch a phonecall from onreceive method of broadcast receiver

Tags: android

when I try to launch this intent sometimes it works and sometime the call ends automatically.i cant figure out the problem.Remember i am doing all this in onReceive().

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:+number"));
     callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     con.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: what do you mean by sometimes.!

Comment: sometimes means 3 out of 5 times it works and 2 times the call ends automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the reply sahilmahajanmj.

Comment: Do you have the right permissions set in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: there should be some specific cases, when it is not working. where you  are installing the app. i mean in emulator or phone.! there might be something wrong with that.

Comment: running it on Galaxy nexus 4.1.1.I have changed the phone too same result.i included android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" permission.

Comment: Anyone with the same issue ?